# boolean does not change in function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, boolean, constants

I have the following code:

```js
const ships = (length) => {
  isSunk = false
  console.log('BEFORE: ' + isSunk)
  const shipSize = length
  let hits = []
  const hitLocation = location => {
    hits.push(location);
    isSunk = true;
    console.log('INSIDE: ' + isSunk)
  }
  console.log('AFTER: ' + isSunk)
  return {
    isSunk,
    hitLocation,
    hits,
    shipSize
  }
}

const two = ships(2)
two.hitLocation(1)
two.hitLocation(2)
console.log('FINAL: ' + two.isSunk)
console.log('HITS: ' + two.hits)
```

Is there a reason why `isSunk` is not saved as `true` when I call it in the end?

Is it due to the nested functions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Comment: When you set a boolean as a property to an object it saves that state at that moment in time. It does not get updated when you update it inside the function. If you used a proper class with getter and setter, you would not have this issue.

Comment: @epascarello any idea why `hits` updates then? I edited the snippet `(console.log('HITS: ' + two.hits)`.

Comment: Because: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: because hits is an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the boolean into the object, it is that value. It is not a reference to the variable. So when you change the variable, the value you saved inside of the object that you returned is not updated.

You can use a function to get the value

```js
const ships = (length) => {
  isSunk = false
  console.log('BEFORE: ' + isSunk)
  const shipSize = length
  let hits = []
  const hitLocation = location => {
    hits.push(location);
    isSunk = true;
    console.log('INSIDE: ' + isSunk)
  }
  console.log('AFTER: ' + isSunk)
  return {
    isSunk: () => isSunk,
    hitLocation,
    hits,
    shipSize
  }
}

const two = ships(2)
two.hitLocation(1)
two.hitLocation(2)
console.log('FINAL: ' + two.isSunk())
```

Other option is to use a class.

```js
class Ship {

    hits = [];
    
    constructor(length) {
        this.shipSize = length;
    }
    
    get isSunk() {
        return this.hits.length === this.shipSize;
    }
    
    hitLocation (location) {
      this.hits.push(location);
      console.log('INSIDE: ' + this.isSunk)
    }
    
}


const two = new Ship(2)
two.hitLocation(1)
two.hitLocation(2)
console.log('FINAL: ' + two.isSunk)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is that `isSunk` is **just a local variable and a value** in contrast to `hits` which is also a local variable but an array and thus just a **reference not a value**.
As you return the object when calling `ship()` these values and the reference get returned in an object.

Now when you call `hitLocation()` it uses the local variable `hits` to add an entry to the array and as the array is just a reference the local variable `hits` and the `hits` in the `two` object have the same reference so they point to the same memory location, thus the update can be seen using the returned object.

On the other hand `hitLocation()` also modifies the local variable `isSunk` but as you do not return that and it is not a reference the object stored in variable `two` is not updated.

The best way to fix this to my mind is using a class instead of a object here. This will be much more concise and clear than returning and/or passing the object you want to perform some action on to a function all the time.